# Python print non-english (telugu) text in readable format

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf

I am processing telugu text to analyze few text tokens.

```
>>> sent = "నా పేరు కరీం ఉంది. నేను భారత ఆహార ప్రేమ.".decode('utf-8')    
>>> text = sent
>>> text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
>>> result = nltk.pos_tag(text)
>>> for val in result:
...     print list(val)[0], list(val)[1]
... 
నా JJ
పేరు NNP
కరీం NNP
ఉంది NNP
. .
నేను VB
భారత JJ
ఆహార NNP
ప్రేమ NNP
```

This way I can see the result in telugu.

For the same text, when I tried this way, it gives unicode string in result. **How can I print token in telugu ?**

```
>>> s = "నా పేరు కరీం ఉంది. నేను భారత ఆహార ప్రేమ.".decode('utf-8')
>>> res = s.split(' ')
>>> res[0]
u'\u0c28\u0c3e'
>>> type(res[0])
<type 'unicode'>
>>> res[0].encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> res[0].encode('utf-8')
'\xe0\xb0\xa8\xe0\xb0\xbe'
```

Edit:

`print res[0]` gave it correctly. But when I executed puting this code in .py script and running it. It gives

```
ubuntu@DELL-PC:~/Documents/codes$ python test.py 
  File "test.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file test.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

test.py contains:

```
s = "నా పేరు కరీం ఉంది. నేను భారత ఆహార ప్రేమ.".decode('utf-8')
a = s.split()
for i in a:
    print i
```

Comment: try `print res[0]` instead.

Comment: What's your problem? Why don't you just `print()` the result: `print(res[0])`?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. print gives it correctly. But issue still persist. I appreciate if you can see the edit in question

Comment: Got to love python - the error message even includes a link to the web page on how to deal with the error.

Comment: the funny literal (word to word) translation of "my name is Karim. I love Indian food". I am reverse translating it literally, "My name Karim is. I India Food Love" just for laughs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have Telugu available in my console easiest answer was to run your python session in a browser by using [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) - that way you get rid of a lot of issues around the terminal character set, etc.

Then I could simply `print` the results:

```
s = "నా పేరు కరీం ఉంది. నేను భారత ఆహార ప్రేమ.".decode('utf-8')
a = s.split()
for i in a:
    print(i)
నా
పేరు
కరీం
ఉంది.
నేను
భారత
ఆహార
ప్రేమ.
```

Note that when putting this sort of thing into a script file you need to start the file with the magic lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8
```

Having deduced that the OP was running python2 I have experimented and found that - *in a terminal that supports utf-8* - the following give results that look to be good when run from a script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function
import nltk

s = "నా పేరు కరీం ఉంది. నేను భారత ఆహార ప్రేమ."  #.decode('utf-8')

a = s.split()
for i in a:
    print(i)

text = nltk.word_tokenize(s.decode('utf-8'))
result = nltk.pos_tag(text)
for val in result:
    print (list(val)[0].encode('utf-8'), list(val)[1])

$ python Untitled2.py
నా
పేరు
కరీం
ఉంది.
నేను
భారత
ఆహార
ప్రేమ.
నా JJ
పేరు NNP
కరీం NNP
ఉంది NNP
. .
నేను VB
భారత JJ
ఆహార NNP
ప్రేమ NNP
. .
```

Comment: Thanks, in Jupyer, it works well. But most of the time I need to write python script and run it on terminal. No way to get rid of this issue if we do it with terminal?

Comment: You obviously have a terminal set up for Telugu have you tried a simple `print(res[0])` to output it?

Comment: If your terminal supports Telugu, then the same thing (that is, `print`) will work. My terminal supports all kinds of Unicode characters just fine, without any special configuration. Perhaps yours does too.

Comment: @RJHunter: thanks. `print(res[0])` prints telugu text. But when I ran it in python script. And executed `python script.py` it gives `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file test.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
` any help for this?

Comment: At the start of your script file you need to have the SheBang and then the encoding lines.

Comment: @user123 You have a non-ASCII characters in the file `test.py` but `test.py` does not declare which non-ASCII encoding it should use. You need to provide an line like `# encoding=utf8` at the top. See http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for more information on exactly how to specify the encoding.